# Horizontal FullPager scroll Animate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I have this simple full-page horizontal scroll code, I would like to add an animate () to give it a 2 second time to scroll but I don't know how. You can also help me by advising me, please.

```
$('#fullpage').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    
  var direction = delta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  
    this.scrollBar = true;
    this.scrollLeft -= jQuery(window).width() * direction;
     
    event.preventDefault();
});
```